# Prove the function $f(x)$ is discontinuous where $f(x)=1$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x≤0$ at the point $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm stuck on this question and I'm not sure how to approach it. I've been solving a few other proofs with the ε-δ property but I don't think I can apply this here. How would I prove that this is discontinuous at the point x=0?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please: 1) Use MathJax to render correctly the math expressions; 2) show us your work done so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

Recall that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists if there exists an $L$ such that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$,
$$
0 < |x - a | < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon.
$$
Negating this property requires flipping all the quantifiers down the chain.  We say $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ **does not** exist if *for every* $L$ *there exists* an $\epsilon>0$ such that *for all* $\delta > 0$ *there exists* a point $x$ such that 
$$
    0 < |x-a| < \delta \text{ and } |f(x) - L| \geq \epsilon.
$$

Any $\epsilon$ that separates $L$ from $1$ or $0$ will work.  Given $\delta > 0$, choose a negative $x$ if $L$ is further than $\epsilon$ from $0$, or a positive $x$ if $L$ is further than $\epsilon$ from $1$.